# Is there a way to sort a file based on a specific slice of each line, where that slice happens to be a date?

Tags: python, sorting, datetime

I have a file, where each line has lots of information. I'm trying to sorted the file based on a specific index of each line which happens to be a date. I know how to sort by date but I can't seem to sort by a slice of a line. Here is a sample line of the file.

`" 001010029xxxxxx                  xxxxxxxxxx        B              V0122200104021918"`
                                                                     `^^^^^^^^`

I want to sort each line based on the indicated **`01222001`** substring.

Here is my sample code but it's not working:

```
sorted_lines = lines.sort(key=lambda x:
    datetime.datetime.strptime(x['date'],
                               'int(lines[69:73])-int(lines[65:67])-int(lines[67:69])'))
```

I get an error `string indices must be integers`. How can I do this?

Comment: try `lines.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[65:73], '%m%d%Y'))`. Note `list.sort()` works inline. If you want to preserve the original list and create new one use `sorted_list = sorted(lines, key=...)`

Comment: or `key=lambda x: (x[69:73], x[67:69], x[65:67])` if you don't want to bother importing `datetime`. Numbers sort lexicographically, so you can just return the strings for `(year, month, day)` and normal tuple sorting should work.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy, good point

Comment: I mean `list.sort()` works inplace, not inline

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `strptime()` because the date string data can be compared directly if you rearrange their component values and put them in year, month, day order.

The following sorts the `lines` list in-place by the date:

```
from pprint import pprint

lines = [                                                          # MMDDYYYY
" 001010029xxxxxx                  xxxxxxxxxx        B              V0122200104021918",
" 001010029xxxxxx                  xxxxxxxxxx        B              V1113200004021918",
" 001010029xxxxxx                  xxxxxxxxxx        B              V0503200104021918",
]

sorted_lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda x: (x[72:76], x[68:70], x[70:72]))
pprint(sorted_lines, width=128)
```

Output:

```
[' 001010029xxxxxx                  xxxxxxxxxx        B              V1113200004021918',
 ' 001010029xxxxxx                  xxxxxxxxxx        B              V0122200104021918',
 ' 001010029xxxxxx                  xxxxxxxxxx        B              V0503200104021918']
```

Comment: Although I agree that `strptime` is not needed, it's still worth pointing out its correct usage, which would have been: `sorted(lines, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[68:76], '%m%d%Y'))`

Comment: @Stef: Point taken, however formally converting the data into a `datetime` object requires more processing and isn't necessary — what I posted was merely the simplest thing that would work.